# Add Ratings and Comments in the same Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, polymorphic-associations, rating, railscasts

I have gotten a comment model to work based on railscast 238 but I would like to add voting and rating as well.

My current show for the article controller is:

```
 def show
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    @commentable = @article
    @comments = @commentable.comments
    @comment = Comment.new


    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @article }
    end
  end
```

I have tried replicating the same process and adding rateable but I do not know how to integrate it into the show action. I have considered creating a universal function from application controller and then trying to assign it in to multiple things(newb) in the show function but that seems over complicated.

I tried adding:

```
@rateable = @article
@ratings = @rateable.ratings
@rating = Rating.new
```

It did not work. But now I am thinking it might work if I assign it to

```
@ratings = Article.find(params[:id]}
@ratings = @rateable.ratings
@rating = Rating.new
```

Even if that does work, there must be cleaner way to do this.

Edit:

Error after correction from this line of code, which is identical to the working comment version.

```
<%= form_for [@rateable, @rating] do |f| %>
  <% if @rating.errors.any? %>
    <div class="error_messages">
      <h2>Please correct the following errors.</h2>
      <ul>
      <% @rating.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_area :content, rows: 8 %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: You just want the parameters `@rateable`, `@ratings`, and `@rating` to all be available in the `show` view?

Comment: Also, why set `@commentable = @article` and `@rateable = @article`? Why not just refer to `@article`?

Comment: When I do that I get  `undefined method article_ratings_path' `

https://github.com/railscasts/154-polymorphic-association-revised/blob/master/blog-after/app/controllers/articles_controller.rb

I am pretty much going off this and don't know how to add another object to the mix.

So the answer to your first question is yes.

Comment: Oh okay, you can just add the second block of code from your question into the `show` method and those variables will be available in your view as well.

Comment: I notice you said doing that "didn't work". If it doesn't I'll need to see the error message. Also, why did you add the `respond_to` block into your version of the `show` method? In the json response you refer to `@articleyi` is that a typo?

Comment: and if it is coming back with the undefined method then that is an error somewhere else in the code?

Comment: What method is it saying is undefined?

Comment: `article_ratings_path`

And yes it is a typo just on stack overflow, not in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, think I figured it out. Just change `<%= f.submit %>` to:

```
<%= f.submit 'Submit', { controller: 'ratings', action: 'create', method: 'post' } %>
```

In your `routes.rb` file you will also need `put '/ratings/create' => 'ratings#create'` or simply `resources :ratings`

This will route your form submit to `ratings#create` which I think is what you want.

Comment: This and changing the route to include ratings was a win!